# Maxima and Minimum of this function

Tags: calculus

I want to find out the maximum and minimum of $e^x\sin x$.
After taking first derivation, the function would be like:
$f'(x) = e^x\cos x + e^x\sin x$
Now, For Critical point $f'(x) = 0$
So,
$0 = e^x(\sin x+\cos x)$

Now how to find $x$ value from above equation?

Can any one reply me step by step and with detail description of all steps?

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming you study $f$ on $\mathbb R$:)

You know that $e^x$ is never $0$, so you have to solve $\sin(x)+\cos(x) = 0$, or $\sin(x) = -\cos(x)$. You must know the values for which this holds (and if you don't remember them, you can draw a circle and find the values on this circle!).

Once you have the values where $f'(x)$ is $0$, you have to check whether $f$ attains a minimum, a maximum or an inflexion point:

- If $f'$ is positive before and negative after $x_0$, $x_0$ is a local maximum of $f$
- If $f'$ is negative before and negative after, it's a local minimum
- If $f'$ doesn't change sign, $x_0$ is an inflexion point (neither a maximum nor a minimum)

Answer (score 0):

$$e^x(\cos x + \sin x)$$
Multiply and divide by $\sqrt{2}$. 
$$\sqrt{2}e^x(\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{2}})$$
$$\sqrt{2}e^x(\sin \frac{\pi}{4}.\cos x + \cos \frac{\pi}{4}.\sin x )$$
We know that:
$$\sin a\cos b + \cos a\sin b = \sin (a+b)$$
Using this identity we arrive at:
$$\sqrt{2}e^x\sin (x + \frac{\pi}{4})$$

$e^x$ is never equal to zero. So $\sin (x + \frac{\pi}{4}) = 0$. From here you will get the value of $x$, which I will leave it to you to calculate.

Comment: thanks but actually i wanted to know from where you got √2e^xsin(x+π/4)? i haven't cleared vision of this?

Comment: @Fhazaie Explained in detail in the edit. Check it out.

Comment: I am still wondering around about the value of x :( as this thing is totally new for me.